# IntelliJ: Run command before opening DB connection. How to achieve it with kubectl port-forward?

Tags: intellij-idea, datagrip

Anyone have a solution to run a port-forward command before connecting to a DB via IntelliJ/DataGrip?

Problem is, the process doesn't exit and the connection can never be opened. Tested this via the `Test Connection` button.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190319

Comment: @s0xzwasd, thank you! Created 4 years ago :-D I have faith.

Comment: now 5 years and counting.